# is there a way to use the spark shipped hdfs delegation token for other hdfs connections in spark submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, kerberos

Here is the scenario: I have a python app that runs spark and I deploy it via spark submit.
spark can access the hdfs, but when I try to access with the hdfs python package (for mkdir for instance) I get authentication problem as if there is no kinit on the driver machine. is there a way to export the hdfs delegation token from the spark context and use it to somehow "kinit" the driver machine?

Comment: Spark runs inside a JVM, and your Python code invokes Java/Scala objects and methods via Py4J interface (and pyspark wrappers around that). If you call the Py4J interface directly to emulate Java code, and call the native HDFS Java API, you might be able to tap the existing tokens. Otherwise...

Comment: `_Java_ = spark.sparkContext._gateway.jvm`

Comment: `tokens_in_static_UGI =_Java_.org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCredentials()`  (??? wild guess - that's a public method but I don't know whether Spark uses the default UGI and whether the HDFS token is stored there and whether it is shown in the getter method)

Comment: And anyway you don't want to mess with the delegation tokens, you want to retrieve the existing instance of the HDFS connector via `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(` _hadoop-conf_ `)` using the Hadoop conf object that - er, is not exposed by PySpark! You have to tap the Spark java API via Py4J, again...

Comment: Long story short: read that blog https://diogoalexandrefranco.github.io/interacting-with-hdfs-from-pyspark/

Comment: Thanks man, gives me something to chew on.